# CSS background images are not showing

Tags: html, css, image

My CSS images are not shown. Everything is relative in the file structure.

```css
.header-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url('/images/header.jpg');
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">
            <h1 id="homeHeading">Your Favorite Source of Free Bootstrap Themes</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap CSS framework! Just download your template and start going, no strings attached!</p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "everything relative wise is right involving the file structure" — How have you confirmed this?

Comment: As you can see here, the image showed up : https://jsfiddle.net/zszf5hff/

Comment: theres something overriding it !

Comment: http://mapitinc.net/mapitinc.net/marketing/splash/ .   thats the url to the link

Answer (score 0):

You are using / to your images path. Remove / before images/header.jpg and try again. Without / it is working fine for me.
You have to wright correct path for image.

Comment: i just tried it its still not working ! idk why i have other css so maybe something is over riding the background image  ?

Comment: something is overiding it how would i be able to find this out ?

Comment: How were you able to test that "Without / it is working fine for me"?

Comment: I tested on my local host with your html and css file.

Where is your background image? Keep image in your images folder and html or css file in same directory there is your images folder have.